# Referencing an IP created by one chef recipe to use in a subsequent recipe of a wrapper cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a wrapper cookbook that executes a series of recipes in order to instantiate several VMs that will communicate with one another.

For example, I have a wrapper cookbook with default recipe:

```
include_recipe 'database'
include_recipe 'application'
```

Inside of database/attributes/default.rb, I define:

```
...
default['database']['bind_address'] = node['ipaddress']
...
```

When the application recipe runs, I would like to use the ip of the created instance for the 'database' recipe in the 'application' template.

The problem I am running into is that when I reference the node['database']['bind_address'] value, I get the ipaddress of the 'application' instance, and not the database instance.

How do I reference the previously created instance's ipaddress in a recipe downstream in the wrapper cookbook?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
normal['application']['bind_address'] = node['ipaddress']
```

in your database attributes file (Or in a attribute file named application.rb in your database cookbook).